# Database trigger or a common method in code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, methods, triggers

I have a table where I want to Log activities of some part of my application. A record will be inserted (may be updated in future) in this table when record inserted/updated in some other table.

E.g.

- If record is inserted in Orders table
  an entry will be inserted in Log
  table.
- If record is inserted in Booking
  table an entry will be inserted in
  Log table.
- if record is updated in Customers
  table an entry will be inserted in
  Log table if Log table does not have
  an entry for this customer.

etc..

Should I use Triggers on these tables to add records in Log table or should I have a common method in my code and call that method whenever insert/update activity occurs?

I have to do this activity on some part of my applications so there can be more than 20 tables on which I will be adding trigger or from couple of different locations from where I will call method.

**I am using SQL Server 2005 and C#**

What is better, Trigger or A method?

Comment: If someone think of better Tags for this question, please edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone has the ability to update the database without your app by using TOAD, SSMS, Query Ananlyzer etc tec, a trigger would be better

Answer (score 5):

Method is better option than Trigger.
Triggers are generally 
- performance heavy
- Less visible in the code, ie are hidden away
- More difficult to debug & Maintain.
- Limits on values to be passed to the log table

A method would give you lots of advantages in terms of optimizing the code, and extending the logic and easier to maintain

Comment: +1: If it's "common", then you have several OO techniques for dealing with this.  Inheritance and delegation are important ways to make this a common part of your application.  Also, in some languages you have "Aspect-Oriented Programming" techniques like "decorators" to make this common feature simple to apply to the relevant classes.

Answer (score 2):

As this seems an important task I would use triggers inside the RDBMS to ensure that not only your application causes the logs to be created.

Comment: This may not seem important now, but could become more important in the future.  Protects against client's directly tampering with the DB and also in case you forget about it in part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

it is never too late for such questions ,
in General , triggers reduce the round trip of your DB and code ,
in your case , to do this in C# you will need 2 trips for each action ,one for the action (Insert) and one for the log action , and of course you need to do a lot of handling for exceptions in your code so if the record is not inserted you handle this and also you log different action of failure
as trigger ,you send the data once to the server and all actions and handling are done there with no extra connections
this is useful specially now that every thing is shared and connections polls are limited .